# Import list from another file

Tags: python

How can I use the list from a .py file that is in the same directory?
Or I know, something like import it.

For example:

**fileone.py**

```
games = ["gears", "kof"]
```

Something like this?

```
from  fileone.py import games

#Now in the filetwo
if var_one in games:
   print("okay")
```

Comment: Drop the `.py` from the import statement; just `from fileone import games`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put your files in same path and import it directly like this :
[image]

Comment: This answer is correct. However I would not use anything like this. But if I had to I would use `from le2 import games`.

Comment: @MSH what do you mean you wouldn't use anything like this? also doing `import le2` is kinda better in the way that it allows the reader to understand from where that thing has come (because instead of some `game` they see `le2.game` so that would indicate that `game` has come from that specific module and what if there are two modules that have a few names that are the same? using the module prefix would be pretty necessary (or could use an alias)), it also doesn't clutter up the namespace

Comment: The idea of importing a variable from another file sounds like a not good idea. Nothing about your answer.

Comment: @MSH not my answer, and also what is wrong about importing a variable from another file? it is much easier and kinda better than having that same exact variable in two places for example if it is used in both files or as I said, it frees up the namespace

Comment: Did not mean to rewrite the same variable. Looks like having these kind of values in a `yaml` or `json`  file is a better approach. So I do not need to look where the origin of the values are.